# How to pass the name of a file from one template to another template , both in different apps in django?

Tags: django

One of my apps is uploading a file . Now I want to add some more attributes with the model built from that file as a foreign key to this table . Let me describe flow a bit more .

1. File A is uploaded by app1
2. app2 uses A's primary key as its foreign key , and creates new tables .

1st task is done . 2nd task is done by importing the model of File A .

My questions are these . 
1. How to make the primary key of app1.model as the foreign key of app 2 . 
2. In the template of app1 , when I click on the url that takes me to app2 template , how to pass the name of File A . So that I can display that I am doing changes related to File A on the template .

I hope I was clear .

Answer (score 1):

View 1:

```
request.session['file_id'] = A.id
```

View 2:

```
file_id = request.session.get('file_id')
```